# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting, Version=10.0.0.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I just installed Visual studio2013 and I am trying to create a Coded UI test. Nothing fancy, just going to a webpage and clicking a link. I am getting the following error. This is not a upgraded project, it's a new project in VS 2013.

Unable to load types from the test source 'c:\users\alomash\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\CodedUITestProject1\CodedUITestProject1\bin\Debug\CodedUITestProject1.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered. If you are running unit tests for Windows Store apps and referencing custom WinMD type then please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238340 for more info. **Error details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting, Version=10.0.0.0,** Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio 2013 did you install? Did you previously have an older version of a different SKU installed? The UI testing tools are only available in VS Premium and above. If you have VS2013 Professional but previously installed VS2010 Ultimate (for example), it could be as simple as you not having the appropriate version of VS to create and execute UI tests.

Comment: I have all VS 2010, VS 2013 professional versions installed. Also, if I write same code in VS 2010 it works fine. It's only when I write it in VS 2013(please note, I am not upgrading), I am writing same code again in different 2013 version. I am using CUITe 1.5 for writing script.

Comment: I have the same issue in a test where both CodedUI & NUnit libs are enabled...

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like Visual Studio is having a hard time finding your DLL. Is the path you've given local to your machine or to another? If not, you will have to change the reference path to that DLL to be relative to your machine.

If this DLL is available as a NuGet package I would recommend getting the DLL from there instead that way you don't have to worry about a specific path, especially if this is a group project that is run on multiple machines.

Hope that helps! I've had similar issues and this worked for me.

Comment: The UI testing tools are not on NuGet, they are part of Visual Studio.

Comment: This is a new test on a new installation. Can't understand why is it looking for version 10 DLL. There is a version 12 DLL already included. If I try adding refernce to version 10 then it's getting conflicted with version 12 DLL. How can I change reference path for 1 DLL?

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to use Visual Studio 2013 Professional to develop your Coded UI tests. Coded UI is only available in the Visual Studio Premium/Ultimate editions. This is why you don't have the necessary assemblies available.

See the Requirements section [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx).

Comment: That did not help, I have the Enterprise edition of Visual Studio 2017, tick-marked Coded UI tests, but I am still getting this error when loading a project. What else can I do to get this assembly?